# Tumbler in C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to implement a tumbler to set the time for an alarm in C++. Yet I've only seen tumblers in Qt quick and therefore coded in QML. Now I've tried to get QML code in my C++ code by doing:

```
void SmartAlarm::showTumbler(){

    // Create the QML view
    QQuickView* quickView = new QQuickView(QUrl(":/files/includes/AlarmTumbler.qml"));

    // Make the QML view resize when the parent is resized
    quickView->setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);

    QWidget* quickWidget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(quickView);
    rightLayout->addWidget(quickWidget);
}
```

My QML file looks like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4

        TumblerColumn{
            id: weekdayTumbler
            model: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
        }
        TumblerColumn {
            id: hourTumbler
            model: 24
        }
        TumblerColumn {
            id: minuteTumbler
            model: 60
        }
```

All I get is a blank, white widget in my layout. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to implement a tumbler in Qt without using QMLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it doesn't find the tumbler-file. You can check this the easiest by starting the program and check in the Application Output (Bottom Menu in QTCreator) for following message:

```
":/files/includes/AlarmTumbler.qml: No such file or directory"
```

If you can't find it, it might be because you use a Shadow Build and the actual execution-files are in a different folder than the QML Files. To solve this, you can go to "Projects" and deactivate "Shadow Build", rebuild and you should see the tumbler.

The implementation itself should work fine. I tested it locally, added everything to the MainWindow though cause I don't know where your "rightLayout" comes from.

```
ui->setupUi(this);

// Create the QML view
QQuickView* quickView = new QQuickView(QUrl("tumbler.qml"));

// Make the QML view resize when the parent is resized
quickView->setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);

QWidget* quickWidget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(quickView);

this->ui->rightLayout->addWidget(quickWidget);
```

Comment: Deactivating Shadow Build fixed the issue. When it was activated, the program was searching in the MinGW Debug folder, but my QML file is located in the folder where my actual program is located (it somehow didn't even throw the message "No such file or directory"). Thank you for the solution!

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the values, that I've set in the tumbler? I would like to work with them in my C++ part but I don't even know how to get them in QML.

Comment: This is only to clarify so I can't add readable code here. Basically you can work with Signals/Slots as described here: 
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html

Comment: You get the Tumbler-Value by adding an "id: firstTumbler" to the qml, then you can access it by firstTumbler.currentIndex  - I added a button to the QML and then an "onClicked - signal that gives the values back to the c++"

Comment: Could you give an example code snippet of how you would implement the button and the signals/slots in my case? I tried it the way it is in the documentation you shared but I am kind of stuck...

Comment: @Schulp Deactivating the shadow build just plasters over the problem. It doesn't solve it. As a part of the build process, you have to either: a) install the QML file in the output folder, or b) add the file as a binary qt resource that would be linked with the executable. Your problem is limited mostly to the project file (either the .pro file if you use qmake, or CMakeLists.txt if you use cmake).